# Boost serialization of recursive objects

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

I defined the following classes to be serialized:

```
using namespace std;

class MyElementObject
{
    friend class boost::serialization::access;

    public:
        template<class Archive>
        void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version) { }
};

template<class T>
class MyRecursiveObject
{
    friend class boost::serialization::access;

    public:
        T element;
        std::vector<MyRecursiveObject<T> > children;

        template<class Archive>
        void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
        {
            ar & element;
            ar & children;
        }
};
```

I then run the following code:

```
int main()
{
    //MyRecursiveObject initialization
    MyRecursiveObject<MyElementObject> rec_object;    
    rec_object.children.push_back(MyRecursiveObject<MyElementObject>());
    rec_object.children[0].children.push_back(MyRecursiveObject<MyElementObject>());

    //create vector of pointers to MyRecursiveObject's elements
    vector<MyElementObject *> elt_ptrs;
    elt_ptrs.push_back(&rec_object.element);
    elt_ptrs.push_back(&rec_object.children[0].element);
    elt_ptrs.push_back(&rec_object.children[0].children[0].element);

    //serialize MyRecursiveObject and the vector of pointers
    {
        ofstream ofs("filename");
        boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
        oa << rec_object;
        oa << elt_ptrs;
    }

    //create new MyRecursiveObject and vector of pointers for deserialization
    MyRecursiveObject<MyElementObject> rec_object_deserialized;    
    rec_object_deserialized.children.push_back(MyRecursiveObject<MyElementObject>());
    rec_object_deserialized.children[0].children.push_back(MyRecursiveObject<MyElementObject>());
    vector<MyElementObject *> elt_ptrs_deserialized;

    //deserialize
    {
        ifstream ifs("filename");
        boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ifs);
        ia >> rec_object_deserialized;
        ia >> elt_ptrs_deserialized;
    }

    //compare deserialized pointers
    cout<<"elt_ptrs first level="<<elt_ptrs_deserialized[0]
    <<" expected="<<&rec_object_deserialized.element<<endl;

    cout<<"elt_ptrs second level="<<elt_ptrs_deserialized[1]
    <<" expected="<<&rec_object_deserialized.children[0].element<<endl;

    cout<<"elt_ptrs third level="<<elt_ptrs_deserialized[2]
    <<" expected="<<&rec_object_deserialized.children[0].children[0].element<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And I always get an output similar to the following one:

```
elt_ptrs first level=0x7fff57c787c0 expected=0x7fff57c787c0
elt_ptrs second level=0x18e7020 expected=0x18e7020
elt_ptrs third level=0xffff8000ab5564f0 expected=0x18e7450
```

As can be observed from the pointer values I manage to deserialize pointers that point to elements down to the second recursion level of MyRecursiveObject. As soon as I try to do it with pointers to the third level or even deeper the deserialization fails.

Am I using boost::serialization wrongly?

Please note that MyRecursiveObject is always successfully deserialized, no matter how many recursion levels it has. I encounter the problem only deserializing pointers to its elements.

Thank you in advance
Kean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's first examine what goes wrong. The default container deserializer basically works like this:

```
size_t count;
ar >> BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(count); // get element count
while( count-- > 0 ) {
    T temp; // <- and here's the problem!
    ar >> boost::serialization::make_nvp("item",temp);
    container.push_back(temp);
}
```

The container (in your case the `vector<MyRecursiveObject<T>>`) is filled using local variables. Unfortunately, their address is registered (object tracking) and referred to when you deserialize the `vector<MyElementObject*>`. In other words, your `elt_ptrs_deserialized` is pointing to local variables that are long gone.

To fix that, serialize the vector manually without using local variables:

```
template<class Archive>
void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
{
    ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(element);
    size_t count = children.size();        // 0 when loading, N when storing
    ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(count);   // load or store element count
    children.resize(count);                // should be a no-op when storing
    while( count-- > 0 )
        ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp("item",children[count]);
}
// You should split serialize() into load() and save() with
// BOOST_SERIALIZATION_SPLIT_MEMBER() for a cleaner version
```

Now, memory for the entire vector is allocated first and the elements are deserialized directly into it, therefore registering the correct memory address. This should yield the desired result:

```
elt_ptrs 1st level=0x22fe90 expected=0x22fe90
elt_ptrs 2nd level=0x6127d0 expected=0x6127d0
elt_ptrs 3rd level=0x613d50 expected=0x613d50
elt_ptrs 4th level=0x613c88 expected=0x613c88
```